# MS Graph API - Paging not working for getSchedule API

Tags: swift, microsoft-graph-api, office365, paging

I have to query for many meeting rooms with email id and I did notice slow results coming from Office 365 API. I did go through their Paging document and when I query using $top=5, I am still getting all 70 results back.

Paging document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging

Request URL - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/getSchedule?$top=5

Do I need to add any other query params to the request? I am noob to Office 365 API.

***Code for requesting meeting room schedule:***

```
public func getScheduleForUnits(emailIds: [String], startDateTime: Date, endDateTime: Date) {
        let request = makeRequest(relativeUrl: "/me/calendar/getSchedule?$top=5")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("outlook.timezone=\"UTC\"", forHTTPHeaderField: "Prefer")

        var payloadDict = [String:Any]()
        payloadDict["schedules"] = emailIds

        let startTime = MSGraphDateTimeTimeZone.fromDate(startDateTime)
        payloadDict["startTime"] = startTime.getDictionary()

        let endTime = MSGraphDateTimeTimeZone.fromDate(endDateTime)
        payloadDict["endTime"] = endTime.getDictionary()

        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: payloadDict)
    }

    private func makeRequest(relativeUrl: String) -> NSMutableURLRequest {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "\(MSGraphBaseURL)\(relativeUrl)")!)
        return request
    }
```

Comment: It seems that you have a `@odata.nextLink` param in the JSON. Use that URL instead for the next one?

Comment: But shouldn't my initial request send me just 5 results since $top param is set to 5? It's returning me all 70 results instead.